# Selenium C# - Assert that an input field is disabled issue

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using Selenium WebDriver with C# I am trying to Assert if an input field is disabled. My Solution has two projects a Tests and a Test Framework.

**Tests**

```
Assert.IsFalse(ContactPage.FirstNameDisabled, "Error: First Name field is not enabled");
```

**Test Framework**

```
  get
        {
            var firstName = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("FirstName"));
            if (firstName.Enabled);
             return false;
            return true;
        }
```

The above code passes whether the fields are disabled or not. I have tried to change around the IsFalse to IsTrue and also the return false, return true order however can't seem to get correct result I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code will always return false because of the `;` at the end of the `if`.  This change should fix it:

```
 get
 {
     var firstName = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("FirstName"));
     if (firstName.Enabled)
         return false;
     return true;
  }
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov True enough.  I hadn't thought beyond fixing the coding issue.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version:

```
get
{
    return !Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("FirstName")).Enabled;
}
```